# libffmpeg.so не загружается в android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Пишу свой плеер для android в котором идет код:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
}
```

а возвращается:

`at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:428)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:369)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:606)
at ru.mysuperproject.android.FFmpeg.<clinit>(FFmpeg.java:25)`

Устройство пытается загрузить его три раза, после чего вылет

Кто знает в чем может быть дело или направит на дельную литературу или пример?

Comment: Вы выложили кусочек стектрейса, но забыли само исключение, которое его прошло.

Comment: проект собрался без ошибок? я имею в виду компиляция ffmpeg и дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: Файлы библиотеки .so я нашел где-то на github, и оттуда-же класс который на их основе ведет себя как плеер. Так что добавив его в проект, тот собрался и запустился на устройстве. но вылетает при инициализации самого плеера в приложении.